# Assign a group name based on identical groups of rows through SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (might end up using Postgres)

Here's how the input looks like.

[image]

I would like to put products into a final grouping based on same criteria.
For example prod-A, prod-B, prod-X all belong to same group as their criteria rows are same. (can't be partial match).

Hence I would like the output to be something like this

[image]
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION WHICH WAS TAGGED POSTGRES.

I think the simplest way is to aggregate the data and then assign the group:

```
select product, dense_rank() over (order by criterias) as grp
from (select product, array_agg(criteria order by criteria) as criterias
      from t
      group by product
     ) p;
```

If you need this on the original data, you can join it in:

```
select t.*, tt.grp
from t join
     (select product, dense_rank() over (order by criterias) as grp
      from (select product, array_agg(criteria order by criteria) as criterias
            from t
            group by product
           ) p
     ) tt
     on t.product = tt.product;
```

You don't even need the extra subquery:

```
select t.*, tt.grp
from t join
     (select product, dense_rank() over (order by criterias) as grp
      from (select product,
                   dense_rank() over (order by array_agg(criteria order by criteria)) as criterias
            from t
            group by product
           ) p
     ) tt
     on t.product = tt.product;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I just realized I won't be able to use Postgresql. Can this be done in SQL server?

Comment: @VM1 . . . I would suggest that you retag this as Postgres and ask another question about SQL Server.